# Jboss 5 EJB 2 transaction timeout on long running queries

Tags: transactions, jboss5.x

In Jboss AS 5.1 we have configured some transaction timeouts in jboss.xml (e.g. 1000 seconds) for our ejbs.

The Problem is that for a long running query the transaction is rolled back after  1000 seconds but the application still waits for the query to come back (e.g after 1200 seconds).

Is there a possibility to stop the query and return a response after 1000 seconds.

We are using oracle database with jboss 5.1.0 GA

Answer (score 1):

> The Problem is that for a long running query the transaction is rolled back after 1000 seconds but
>    the application still waits for the query to come back.

The aim of transaction timeout limit, is to avoid that a long-running transaction locks the database resources beyond an
acceptable period of time.
There is no guarantee the thread that executes the business logic will be interrupted when 
the transaction timeout expires.

> Is there a possibility to stop the query and return a response after 1000 seconds.

I think what you need is to decouple the query execution from the Client, to achieve this you could  execute the query asynchronously.

Since java 6, this can be implemented using [asynchronous method invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).
The idea is expose the query as an asynchronous service. Once the service (query) is invoked the Client doesn't need wait for the query finalization. Notice that to maintain the timeout limit is important despite the fact that the Query executes asynchronously.